# ¿Necesito el paquete XAMPP para practicar con PHP?

Tags: php, backend

Si es así, ¿Cómo puedo configurar PHP, de forma que entienda los pasos que se van realizando para la configuración del servidor embebido de PHP?

Comment: No lo necesitas, XAMPP o WAMPP ya lo hace por ti. No necesitas nadamas que instalarlo. ( A menos que quieras ser un master )

Comment: No, pero depende en qué SO estás trabajando ?

Comment: por favor lee los siguientes enlaces y mejora tu pregunta [ask] y de paso haz el [tour] para comprender mejor como funcionamos. Saludos

Comment: Vale, muchas gracias .. intentaré reformular la pregunta....